# How to skip the last iteration of a for loop in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to skip the final iteration of my for loop that i am running on a dataframe as it is giving incorrect results. This might be a very trivial problem and need help on this as i am new to python.I have my data spanning into millions of rows and a few hundred thousand ids.

I have a dataframe(df) with 3 columns ID,Event,Time. I am trying to compute another column TimeDiff, which is the difference between events for a particular id, can also be referred to as time to live for a particular event.

```
ID|Event|Time|TimeDiff
1|x|hh|hh(y)-hh(x) 
1|y|hh|hh(z)-hh(y)
1|z|hh|Nan
2|x|hh|hh(y)-hh(x) 
2|y|hh|Nan
```

Above is the desired output but the approach i am trying gives me a value for Nan as well which is basically the time difference with the next event and next id which ideally should be Nan.

```py
for i in df.Id.unique():
    df['TimeDiff'] = (df['Time'].shift(-1) - df['Time']).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

Expected Result:

```
ID|Event|Time|TimeDiff
1|x|hh|hh(y)-hh(x) 
1|y|hh|hh(z)-hh(y)
1|z|hh|Nan
2|x|hh|hh(y)-hh(x) 
2|y|hh|Nan
```

Actual Result:

```
ID|Event|Time|TimeDiff
1|x|hh|hh(y)-hh(x) 
1|y|hh|hh(z)-hh(y)
1|z|hh|hh(x)-hh(z)
2|x|hh|hh(y)-hh(x) 
2|y|hh|Nan
```

If i am able to skip the final for loop iteration for my id no 1, i will be able to get the desired solution

Comment: check with groupby diff

Comment: @WeNYoBen can u explain a bit in detail...i am not able to make sense of this...

Comment: @WeNYoBen thanks the solution using groupby diff worked...but its taking sometime to complete the execution due to millions of datapoints..